# Job requires 6 hour commute every month. What compensation and considerations should I expect?

Tags: united-states, travel, reimbursement

Let me start by saying I have just interviewed and been offered the position, but have not accepted yet. I want to make sure I know the correct things/way to ask questions when I call back to clarify, especially since our current schedules make communicating through voicemail sometimes necessary.

The job is doing scribe work in a Dr. office that every month (or every other) does clinic hours both in a city 1 hour away and in a city 3 hours away. So that means I will have a day of work where I am in the car for 6 hours!

What do I need to find out to make sure the job is worth it? Do jobs typically pay your hours when traveling in this sort of situation? Is the 'mileage reimbursement' worth it, especially considering wear and tear on the car?

Anything else I should know?

Comment: Are you  getting paid for traveling time to the distant office?

Comment: @zabeus I guess it would be something like the company pays you for the fuel spent to drive to the place.

Comment: Are they asking you to drive the 6 hours and work a full 8 hours,  or is there some other arrangement for the commute, like drive the evening before, stay in a provided hotel room overnight and return home the following day, or working for only a half day?

Comment: @MaskedMan The IRS has a mileage rate that covers not just fuel expenses, but wear and tear on the car.  In theory the company should pay this as a minimum for private vehicle use.

Answer (score 6):

I would ask if they pay you for your drive time when you have to do the extra commuting.  ( this won't help if you are paid with salary )  You can also ask if they reimburse you for mileage.

Besides these two things, you can **negotiate a higher salary or hourly rate** to help compensate for the extra time required on the *severe* travel occasions.

Somehow you need to get compensated for the extra time and wear and tear on you car.

Comment: Why does this answer warrant a down vote?

Comment: It doesn't deserve a downvote

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say in which country you live.

In the UK, the time that you drive to a different place than your normal place of work should count as working time, and you should either get your travel cost (if you drive by train, for example) or 45 pence per mile driven by car, up to 10,000 miles a year, tax free.

Is it worth it? Well, if you drove 10,000 miles a year for 10 years, that would be £45,000 which would probably more than pay for your car, repairs, maintenance, insurance, and fuel.

Comment: Sorry. I am in the U.S.

Comment: @user65421 Similar rules apply in the US, and the IRS has a standard mileage rate used for reimbursement: [2017 Standard Mileage Rates for Business](https://www.irs.gov/uac/2017-standard-mileage-rates-for-business-and-medical-and-moving-announced)